# "No candidates found for method call println"

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

Im relatively new to Gradle and I tried to write my first own task.
My problem is, that Intellij shows some methods of my build script as 'not found', but executing the task seems to work without any problem.
I already tried invalidating my cache, and I also restartet the Idea. I even tried it with other projects but nothing seems to work.
[When I hover over println (or, not in the screenshot "do last") it shows the error specified in the title of this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqCC6.png)

Comment: IntelliJ is well known for its poor support of Gradle Groovy DSL. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Moreover, you are inlining a task definition in your build script. I would say it could too much for IntelliJ to handle :)

Comment: As far as I can see from your screenshot, your `Main` file is a `.java` file. No idea why it's working though. Usually groovy scripts have a square icon in IntelliJ, your `Main` class has round icon.

Comment: Make sure the **Reload** action in Gradle tool window is completed successfully. Also try 2022.3 version from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2022.3+latest+builds It has better support for build Gradle files.

Comment: I am facing similar issues with maven, do let me know if there's a solution you did